# Can non-rfc1918 ranges in peered VPCs be overlapping if they are not exported?

Tags: google-compute-engine

If two VPCs are peered and both use non-RFC1918 subnetworks, can those subnetworks have overlapping CIDR ranges? Does it depend on whether [`import-subnet-routes-with-public-ip` / `export-subnet-routes-with-public-ip`](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#subnet-route-exchange) are used?

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering says "A subnet CIDR range in one peered VPC network cannot overlap with a static route in another peered network. This rule covers both subnet routes and static routes." This mentions nothing about whether the routes are exported or not. Neither does https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#interaction-subnet-subnet. So it seems that subnetworks cannot be overlapping. However, its not explicitly called out, and so is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, non-rfc1918 ranges in a peered VPCs can be overlapped if both sides of the peering did not import the non-rfc1918 subnet.

i.e

```
import_subnet_routes_with_public_ip: false
```

All the ranges defined here in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#valid-ranges) will be treated as non-public IP.

1. Non-public IP addresses from this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#valid-ranges) are always exchanged regardless of the value of allow_subnet_routes_with_public_ip. If those ranges overlap, then VPC peering is not allowed.
2. If allow_subnet_routes_with_public_ip is false, then the user can have overlapping public IP subnets, but those won't be exchanged.
3. If allow_subnet_routes_with_public_ip is true, then the user cannot have overlapping public IP subnets, otherwise the peering will be rejected.
4. If a non-public IP subnet. say 198.18.0.0/15, is expanded to 198.18.0.0/14 into the public range, then it will be treated as a public IP range subnet, and rules (2) and (3) above will apply to it.